# VIM how to suround each element in a list with quote and comma

Tags: vim, vi

say I have a list

> 1M 3M 5D 3Y 9Y

I want to quickly turn this list into "1M", "3M", "5D", "3Y", "9Y" using vim -- so far I was doing it manually. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:%s/[^ ]\+/"&",/gc` replaces tokens by `"token",`. `c` is for confirmation.

Comment: @vehomozzz `[^ ]` means any symbol, but not space, `\+` means one or more, `&` means the matched text (`g` means global - search the whole string, `c` means ask before replacing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [surround plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) with macros.